# Cypher query to find all paths with same relationship type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggling to find a single clean, efficient Cypher query that will let me identify all distinct paths emanating from a start node such that every relationship in the path is of the same type when there are many relationship types.

Here's a simple version of the model:

```
CREATE (a), (b), (c), (d), (e), (f), (g),
       (a)-[:X]->(b)-[:X]->(c)-[:X]->(d)-[:X]->(e),
       (a)-[:Y]->(c)-[:Y]->(f)-[:Y]->(g)
```

In this model `(a)` has two outgoing relationship types, `X` and `Y`. I would like to retrieve all the paths that link nodes along relationship `X` as well as all the paths that link nodes along relationship `Y`.

I can do this programmatically outside of cypher by making a series of queries, the first to 
retrieve the list of outgoing relationships from the start node, and then a single query (submitted together as a batch) for each relationship. That looks like:

```
START n=node(1) 
MATCH n-[r]->() 
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT TYPE(r)) as rels;
```

followed by:

```
START n=node(1) 
MATCH n-[:`reltype_param`*]->() 
RETURN p as path;
```

The above satisfies my need, but requires at minimum 2 round trips to the server (again, assuming I batch together the second set of queries in one transaction).

A single-query approach that works, but is horribly inefficient is the following single Cypher query:

```
START n=node(1) 
MATCH p = n-[r*]->() WHERE 
   ALL (x in RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE TYPE(x) = TYPE(HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)))) 
RETURN p as path;
```

That query uses the `ALL` predicate to filter the relationships along the paths enforcing that each relationship in the path matches the first relationship in the path. This, however, is really just a filter operation on what it essentially a combinatorial explosion of all possible paths --- much less efficient than traversing a relationship of a known, given type first.

I feel like this should be possible with a single Cypher query, but I have not been able to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minor optimization, at least non-matching the paths will fail fast:

```
MATCH n-[r]->() 
WITH distinct type(r) AS t 
MATCH p = n-[r*]->() 
WHERE type(r[-1]) = t // last entry matches
RETURN p AS path
```

This is probably one of those things that should be in the Java API if you want it to be really performant, though.